# Insight into code history? Discovery of old classes that have been deleted in version control (vcs/scm)?

Tags: git, svn, plugins, version-control, ide

Does anyone know if there are any plugins or practices that can assist a developer on the history of code?

The scenario I am presenting is for code that has significant history. There could be classes related to what you are working on that may have been removed. There could be code that once did what you are trying to accomplish but was discarded because more important things arose.

But the case is, you don't know what you don't know. Are there any tools that can quickly  highlight significant events to the package and/or code you are working on that may give you some insight into its history that could help improve your course of action/development?

This is a complicated problem area where the benefits of its solution uncertain, but just wondering if there is anything out there.

Comment: I think this question is far too open ended to get very good answers.  If you have a specific problem you're working on that'd be likely to get a better answer.

Comment: I disagree with your logic that open ended questions cannot garner quality answers. If you don't have an answer, fine.

Answer (score 0):

[SemanticMerge](http://www.semanticmerge.com/index.html#features) (at least for some languages) can compare structured code, not just text-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Try open source tool [Hercules](https://github.com/src-d/hercules). There are some analysis types which may help in your case: burndown and developers timeline. It also can show structural hotness, such as functions or classes.